Need help with correcting potential short circuits in inverter diagram
I recently made this inverter circuit, I believe that there are some potential short-circuit issues in my diagram.
I could be wrong tho.
There are two groups of NPN transistors in my circuit, A and B.
Only one group stays active at a time. Each group has two transistors, both are connected as such that they activate at the same time. Both groups are connected to the control signal, as the B group is directly connected, and A is connected with a not gate.
So when the control signal is On, A stays on and B stays off, and vice versa.
Now, here's my diagram:

Now as you can see in the diagram, the emitter of transistor A on the VCC goes to the base of transistor B on the ground side. Now here's the problem.
If the current goes through from VCC, to the emitter of A and then to the base of B, would it go to the ground directly from there and cause a short circuit? Or am I wrong here?
Or what else could happen? All the transistors are NPN.
Just need help with that, thank you!

*Now as you can see in the diagram, the emitter of transistor A on the VCC goes to the base of transistor B on the ground side. * Not sure I can see that.  Not sure I can make heads or tails of the diagram at all.  What are the specs for your circuit? What is it trying to achieve? What are the inputs and outputs? (Levels, frequencies, etc.)  What are the component values and part numbers?

I am just new to electronics. I am just a new guy to this stuff. I am just trying to make an inverter using a micro controller. That converts dc to ac. And I am confused if it would get shorted on no.

Also, sorry but I have no knowledge about their values and other similar things. I made A PWM generated signal through my microcontroller and it looks more like a rectified AC signal with no additional things like capacitors or other similar components. Now I am looking to make an inverter circuit to generate an actual AC wave or whatever we call it. I made it so that whenever it is the negative half of the signal, Pin number 14 on the controller turns on so I can turn on the inverter to make it negative. Thanks,
